# What editor does stackoverflow use?

Tags: discussion

I realy like the editor stackoverflow uses. its nice, plain and simple. **Also I realy like the auto image upload to imgur.com** Is there any editor out there which can give me the similar functionality specially the image upload feature

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange websites implement [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), and also a couple extra special features (imgur uploading). If you implement some text editor with Markdown, it will have many of the same features.

See: [markdownsharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/), and the [blog post here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/).